# suggest using webapplicationbuilder.configuration instead of configureappconfiguration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022, azure-keyvault, .net-7.0

I am trying to read value from appsettings.Development.json file using Managed Identity for.NET 7 asp.net core web api application using Visual Studio 2022 (Enterprise Edition)

Here goes the code for Program.cs :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var config = builder.Configuration;

// Add AzureKeyVault

    builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, appConfig) =>
    {
        var objBuiltConfig = appConfig.Build();
        var userAssignedClientId = objBuiltConfig[AppKeys.UserAssignedClientId];
        var objSecretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(objBuiltConfig[AppKeys.KeyVaultURL]),
            new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId
            }));
        config.AddAzureKeyVault(objSecretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager());
    });
```

In the code editor I am seeing the warning :

suggest using webapplicationbuilder.configuration instead of configureappconfiguration

Even on debugging I am not getting the data.

Can anyone help me here with some code sample which will serve as a reference for my implementation

====================update======================

```
var userAssignedClientId = config[AppKeys.UserAssignedClientId]; 
var keyVaultURL = config[AppKeys.KeyVaultURL]; 

builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(uriString: keyVaultURL), new 
     DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { 
          ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId }));
```

But now I see swiggle with keyVaultURL within the `new Uri(uriString: keyVaultURL)`. I wanted to know why it is coming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, appConfig) =>
{
    config.AddAzureKeyVault(...);
});
```

Change to this:

```
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(...);
```

Here's an example of this sort of approach for an application I maintain: [github.com/martincostello/SignInWithAppleSample](https://github.com/martincostello/SignInWithAppleSample/blob/ecfca1e7a285efe1edc24cfc2db66c76f1f6669f/src/SignInWithApple/WebApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L12-L34)

Comment: Thanks @MartinCostello for your response. I have the updated the code : var userAssignedClientId = config[AppKeys.UserAssignedClientId];
var keyVaultURL = config[AppKeys.KeyVaultURL];
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(uriString: keyVaultURL),
                                       new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId })); But now I see swiggle with keyVaultURL within the new Uri(uriString: keyVaultURL). I wanted to know why it is coming. Any help on this request is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Do I have the same swiggle with you under `keyVaultURL` ? If so then `new Uri(uriString: keyVaultURL ?? ""`. Hope I misunderstood your issue.

[image]

Any way I just want to share the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0) about using azure key vault in asp.net core and the [sample code](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/security/key-vault-configuration/samples).

[image]